# Find out when user was added to Exchange 2010 distribution group

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

Is there a way to find out when user was added to distribution group and by who? Probably thru AD or Exchange Management Console? Or such information is not stored anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Directory Service Change auditing enabled, there would be a 5136 event in the security event log on the domain controller where the change was made.

You can also identify when the *member* attribute was last changed.  If the dl does not change often, this may help if the last change was when that account was added to the dl.

```
repadmin /showobjmeta <dcname> "<dn of distribution list>"
```

results:

```
29 entries.
Loc.USN                           Originating DSA  Org.USN  Org.Time/Date        Ver Attribute
=======                           =============== ========= =============        === =========
 409215      1b022a66-0f20-440d-b6f6-9a9b3b83b83c  36538059 2006-01-24 16:04:24    1 objectClass  
 409215      90864325-7d94-48ef-b941-9a1595ce749c 103330135 2008-06-02 09:22:57   22 member
```

**Audit Directory Service Changes**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772641%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: The repadmin helped a lot. For each member it showed: PRESENT       member 2012-06-22 13:30:49          Domain\AD2 (deleted DSA)   20181 21139211   1 ...OBJECT... In Windows 2012 the ID's were 4761, 4760.